# jquery.getScript - how to set attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I create a script by simply doing

`jQuery.getScript('hi.js').done(function(script){ /*script is a plain text */})`

as we see, "done"'s parameter is "script", but it is just a text of loaded script. However I need access to the element itself! What if I want to set its ID to "helloScript"?

In vanilla js I can do this:

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = url;
script.setAttribute('id', 'helloScript'); // <----------------------- this!
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
```

but how to do this in jQuery, I wonder?

Comment: maybe this answer will be help you, please check http://stackoverflow.com/a/3206145/3967587

Comment: Doesn't look like `getScript()` provides the ability to do this. Why not just use Vanilla JS, since you already have the code?

Comment: I'd recommend just staying with the vanilla Javascript because it seems to solve your problem more completely. You could use `getScript()` and then after the script is loaded, go find the script tag by searching all script tags for the one with the right source in it and add the id to it - though I can't imagine why you'd do it that when when the vanilla js is simpler and works just fine.

Comment: I can't use vanilla JS, because I don't know how to detect the fact that it was not loaded, there is no ".fail()" facility, you have to do both "readyState" and "script.onerror" (or even maybe something else for some browser I don't know about).

Answer (score 3):

Since you cannot (sadly) do it with jQuery, you could do it without like so, which is a big simpler than how you did it in your question:

```
// create script tag
var s = document.createElement('script');

// set script attributes
s.async = 1;
s.src = [whatever];

// inject to DOM
document.head.appendChild(s);
```

I think that it is possible to know which script was injected and then alter it's attributes, but it seems not to be working. I will investigate further on the jQuery github. seems to be a discussion about this exact thing [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/3028).

---

Seems like it will be available in jQuery version `3.2.0` and will work like so:

```
$.ajax({
  dataType : "script",
  url      : "https://some/path",
  attrs    : { nonce: "EDNnf03nceIOfn39fn3e9h3sdfa" },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like `.getScript()` provides a way to access the element it creates, but you could utilize jQuery to simplify your vanilla approach a little bit:

```
$('<script>')
    .attr('id', 'helloScript')
    .attr('src', url)
    .appendTo('head');
```

**Edit:** I can't seem to find a way to get script onload events to run when creating and attaching the script using jQuery, so if you need that, you may need to go the Vanilla JS route.

Comment: @TheProHands - the small difference between 50k points and 660 ;)

Comment: @vsync But I answered first. I answered the same thing and they downvoted me. Weird. And he commented later than my answer.

Comment: Why are people recommend replacing four lines of plain javascript with four lines of jQuery?  It's just non-sensical.  jQuery should be used only when it's actually better - which it does not appear to be in this case.  My recommendation would be to stick with the plain Javascript implementation.

Comment: @jfriend00 The question is about jQuery and OP is asking for a jQuery solution. Using jQuery here reduces the code to about half as many characters and makes it more readable, so if OP is already using jQuery, why not use it here?

Comment: @TheProHands If it's any consolation, I got a downvote too :)

Comment: Because, as you say, you can't see when the script is loaded this way.  It's a less capable implementation.  jQuery should be used when it is actually better.  It's not something to worship and to strive to write all your code in.  It's a tool.  Use the right tool for the job.